# ssh2-sftp-client put method returns ENOENT: no such file or directory, open

Tags: node.js, sftp, ssh2-sftp-client

I'm trying to write a simple csv file to a server using sftp.

Here's my code:

```
const insertSftpFiles = async (sftp: SFTPClient, path: string, countryCode: CountryCode, archivePath: string, file: any, connectionConfig: any) => {
    const csvData = jsonConvertToCsv([{ "a": "1", "b": "2"}]);

    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(csvData);

    const remote = "/inbound/hello.csv";
    
    sftp.connect(connectionConfig).then(() => {
        return sftp.put(readStream, remote);
    })
    .then(() => {
        return sftp.end();
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err.message);
    });
}
```

My csvData is a proper csv string and i can connect to my server and even get files but when I try put I get this error:

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '"a","b" "1","2"'